# Set Iterator toString - JAVA

Tags: java, iterator, set, tostring

I'm doing an assignment and within my class, I have a Set in order to read multiple authors for my Book class.  I'm trying to figure out how to properly implement the toString.  Would I do the toString as normal and then implement the Iterator such as this:

```
public String toString(){
       Iterator itr = set.iterator();
       while(itr.hasNext()){
           Object element = itr.next();
       }

       Return "Book, ISBN:" + isbn +", Author:" + element
}
```

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well, you have too many `return`s in that code, especially the first line.  Try just one as the very last line.

Comment: So take out the return on the first line, and the return within the iterator?

   while(itr.hasNext()){
     //code
   }
 
   return "Book, isbn =" + isbn + ", Author:" + element;

Is that correct?

Comment: *Does that make any sense?* no. First of all, toString(), as its name indicates, is supposed to return a String, not a Set<String>. And the method starts by returning a String, and then do other stuff. Since it has returned already, all the lines after will never execute. Do you understand what return means? Finally, this obviously doesn't compile. So, why don't you read the error messages you get from the compiler?

Comment: JB, I understand what you're saying.  This is my first Java class and I'm still getting my feet wet.  I've taken quite a few other classes and understand you can only return once.  Oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to use exactly the same method signature of toString, which is:

```
public String toString()
```

Second, the first line in your implementation is a return statement, which renders the rest of your lines unreachable.

Third, putting a return statement in a loop is always debatable.

Although I am not quite sure how you want to implement your toString, but you need to change these first.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought something more like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Book, isbn =" + isbn + ", Author: ");
    for (String s : authorSet) {
        sb.append(s).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'll ask my professor, but I'm not sure he wants us to use that yet.  Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

You have to match the signature exactly.  Use the `@Override` annotation to make certain you have done so.  Second look at `StringBuilder` to create a new string in small steps.  However for this problem you can probably get by with just `+`.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
       String retString = "Book, isbn =" + isbn + ", Author:";
       Iterator itr = set.iterator();
       while(itr.hasNext()){
           Object element = itr.next();
           retString = retString + element.toString();
       }
       return retString;
}
```

There's little ways this could be improved, I'll let you work on those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're now first iterating over the whole set, thus making element the final entry in your set first.

```
 while(itr.hasNext()){
       Object element = itr.next();
   }

   Return "Book, ISBN:" + isbn +", Author:" + element
```

Now your return will always be the same book object.

You should try something more like:

```
String res = "";
while(itr.hasNext()){
    res = res + element.toString() + "\n";
}return res;
```

This would be a solution without using StringBuilder.